# Package resolution failed. Couldn't get the list of tags

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Can't add new dependency via SPM and always see this error
[image]

> fatal: bad numeric config value 'null' for 'tag.forcesignannotated': invalid unit

1. Clean derived data, reset package caches, resolve package version, restart Xcode - not work.
2. Xcode 12.5.1 and Xcode 13 - not work (this error above)
3. Xcode 12.4 - kill Xcode and close it

But I can add dependency via cocoapods.

Please help

Comment: I fixed that due to 
`git config --global tag.forcesignannotated false`

Comment: Can't reproduce. I added _https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift_ to my project just fine. Is there something odd about how you're adding it?

Comment: OK, that's really interesting and you should give it as an answer.

Comment: @matt thanks! I had that bug in my new MacBook. In old - everything is ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed that due to next command:

```
git config --global tag.forcesignannotated false
```

Comment: you save my life !

Comment: What does that do...?

Comment: @Arturo 
The main point of the command git config --global tag.forcesignannotated false is to configure Git so that it does not require GPG signatures for annotated tags on a global level for the user. This setting affects all repositories the user works with, making it optional to sign annotated tags with a GPG key, which can simplify workflows in environments where such security measures are not necessary or desired.

Answer (score 1):

before starting to load the SPM change the version to minor and you are good to go.